# how to make input in python non-punctuation sensitive

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a french practice chatbot however users may not type the punctuation in the code. how do I fix this? this is my code. for example, I want to make it so that no matter what you type, like instead of "bonjour!" they can type "bonjour" only with no punctuation sensitivity. this may be not possible without a module but I don't care if it requires a module

```
#menu starts first
line1 = ("=-----------=")
line2 = ("-------------")

bots = ["Adam", "Marie", "James", "Joy"]


def conversation():
    print("For your conversation, Choose a Bot")
    print(line1)
    for bot in bots:
        print(bot)
    print(line2)
    botopt = input("option: ")
    if botopt==("Adam").lower():
        print("adam: Bonjour!")
        msg = input("Type a message: ")
        if msg==("Bonjour! Comment ca va?").lower():
            print("adam: Très bien. et toi?")
            msg = input("Type a message: ")
            if msg==("Tres bien. Comment tu t'appelle?").lower():
                print("adam: Je m'appelle Adam. Et toi?")
                input("Name: ")
                print("adam: Enchante. ")


def menu():
    print("Bonjour! Please choose an area to practice on.")
    wordoption = ["Verbs"]
    placeoption = ["Restaurant", "Store", "Conversation"]
    #pour le optionnes

    print("Vocabulary")
    print("=----------=")
    for wopt in wordoption:
        print(wopt)
    print("=---------=")
    print("Locations")
    print("-----------")
    for popt in placeoption:
        print(popt)
    print("--------------")
    opt = input("option: ")

    if opt==("Conversation").lower():
        conversation()

menu()
```

i cant find info online so i am not sure what to do, so please try to help me, send me modules if needed

Comment: More than that, your code requires all of the capitalization to match exactly, and of course, it requires the messages to be in exactly the right order.  You have a fair amount of work in front of you.  You should probably be removing punctuation, converting to lower case, and looking for key words, instead of matching whole sentences.  Genuine natural language processing is quite difficult.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for that I'm quite new i would say I'm around intermediate so ill try that

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to python, so if my suggestion(s) do not seem adequate to you, then don't use them. I use Python v3.10.2, and tested my solution in IDLE shell v3.10.2.

In the header portion of your code, you typed:

> line1 = ("=-----------=")
> and line2 = ("-------------")

I believe these are global variables, because these appear outside a defined function. You used these effectively in conversation(), your first function:

> ```
>  print(line1)
> ```
>
> > ```
> > for bot in bots:
> > print(bot)
> > ```
>
> ```
>  print(line2)
> ```

But, you did not use these in menu(), the second function. Why not? If for no other reason, I suggest you use it in the second function as well for consistency. This should improve your programming style, and make it easier for others to understand your code.

For the punctuation problem, I think you can probably work this out without the need of an additional module. If I understand the problem correctly, you don't want users to enter punctuation of any kind (! , . : ; - " ') in response to your code. Is this right? If so, you want users to be confined to using letters A-Z or a-z and nothing else in their response.

You could create another function that takes a single argument, such as:

def Response(msg):

```
# create an empty string for processed word with punctuation removed
rsp = ''
#msg = "Bonjour!"
for c in range(len(msg)):
    word = msg[c]    # index of 1st character in msg string = 0, 2nd = 1, 3rd = 2, etc. . .
    # add exceptions here
    if word != '!':    # exclamation mark
        rsp = rsp + word
    elif word != ',':    # comma
        rsp = rsp + word
    elif word != '.':    # period
        rsp = rsp + word
    # etc...
    else:
        print('Please, do not use punctuation of any kind.')

print (word)
```

Keep in mind that this will work for single words input from the user. For full sentences, you'll have to allow for spaces to be used for word spacing.

Also, the French comment in the menu() definition should read:

## pour les options

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to clearly answer your question.

### The Problem

First, your code uses capitalization in such a way that the capitalization of the input has to match that of the strings you're checking it with.

To fix that, I recommend making all your input string AND the input-checking strings **lowercase** and **unpunctuated**.
To do that, you can either chose to manually adjust all your checking strings, or you can just use `str.lower()`.

To allow the user to only input unpunctuated and lowercase text, you can make your own function `customInput()` that works like `input()` but also removes all punctuation, and also lowercases the text before `return`.

### Normal code

Here is the code, feel free to use/modify:

```
# you NEED to import this for the unpunctuation to work
from string import punctuation

# this is a function that works like input(), but removes all punctuation and makes the input lowercase
def customInput(text:str):
    inputText = input(text).lower()
    for character in [symbol for symbol in punctuation]:
        inputText = inputText.replace(character,'')
    return inputText

# do remember to use string.lower() on the strings you check the input with
```

### Code for also removing numbers

If you want to remove numbers too from the input, then you can use this code:

```
# you NEED to import these for the unpunctuation to work
from string import punctuation, digits

# this is a function that works like input(), but removes all punctuation and numbers, and makes the input lowercase
def customInput(text:str):
    inputText = input(text).lower()
    for character in [symbol for symbol in punctuation] + [number for number in digits]:
        inputText = inputText.replace(character,'')
    return inputText

# do remember to use string.lower() on the strings you check the input with
```

### Example usage

```
# an example of using customInput()
example = customInput('Saisissez une réponse: ')

# printing answer out
print(example)

# There will be no punctuation/capitalization in the printed output
```

Hope this helps! If it doesn't, comment and I will update the answer.